# EUI Edge Router Load Balancing and Failover error

Tags: load-balancing, configuration, failover, ubiquiti-edgerouter

I unfortunately still have the problem that the Edge Router for some reason all the time uses VDSL and cellular at the same time without reason, although everything is configured as a failover so that when cable internet is down or disabled first VDSL is used via PPPOE2 interface and then only when VDSL fails cellular should be used I am accurate.

Comment: what is the business related question in here and what is the business related hardware that has been affected by this?

Comment: There's no config here, only some description. This isn't an answerable question as it stands; you need to show us config and explain what you're attempting to achieve.

Comment: The hardware is a Ubiquiti Edge Router 12
And regarding the config I tried to post it but I get message that the characters are too much.